# chrome.commands -- Any support for more characters?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm playing around with the [chrome.commands](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands.html) functionality and I was noticing that there really aren't very many viable keybinds.

I was wondering if there would ever be support for a wider range of characters? Currently I can only do A-Z, but it would be nice if I could do ">" "<", arrow keys, etc... basically the entire jQuery keycode set.